# Is this a valid DynamoDB access pattern (having "detailed" and "relational" items)?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries

I am building an application using DynamoDB. High level details are: there are users, there are communities' (which users can join), and there are posts (essentially, same use case as Reddit).

My question is how to construct the data in DynamoDB. I am currently using the pattern of having main items (these items are users, posts, communities) which have the exact same partition key and sort key, and these items will always have all details. I'll call these items "detailed" items.
For example, a "detailed" user item would look like this:

```
Partition Key: USER#<id> 
Sort Key:      USER#<id>
```

It would be similar with posts and communities:

```
Partition Key: POST#<id> 
Sort Key:      POST#<id>
```

```
Partition Key: COMMUNITY#<id>
Sort Key:      COMMUNITY#<id>
```

Now, in order to have relations between these entity's, other items will be created which I am going to call "relational" items. So, if a user posts something, a relational item will be created like this:

```
Partition Key: USER#<id> 
Sort Key:      POST#<id>
```

The whole purpose of this "relational" item is just to make it apparent the user has created this post, and it allows for a simple query to get all the posts a user has created.

Now the problem, these "relational" items do not have any of the data of the detailed item, meaning that after doing a query to get all the users posts, batch get would then have to be used to get the "detailed" items (costing more RCU's).
To be clear, the data is not replicated in the "relational" item because posts can be edited, so the duplicating the details could lead to inconstancies.

Is this an appropriate way to access data, are there better ways? Is the cost of doing batch get negligible enough? Should the data just be duplicated, and if something is edited, updated both items? Just looking for outside opinions.

I have tried having no "detailed" items and having the "relational" items have all the details. However, this complicates the requests since I need both the PK and SK to delete or update an item (compared to a single key since PK and SK would be the same). Additionally, this pattern seems more streamlined in implementing, if it's an object/model in the code, then it is a "detailed" item in the database.

Comment: What you are asking here is [should data be normalized or denormalized](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/should-your-dynamodb-table-be-normalized-or-denormalized/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the "link entity" by placing the user id in the SK of the post.

```
PK                      SK
POST_USER_ID#<user_id>  POST_ID#<post_id>
```

This way you can do two types of queries

- Query all with `PK==POST_USER_ID#123` that will give you all posts of a user
- Query all with `PK==POST_USER_ID#123` `SK==POST_ID#<post_id>` will give you a specific post by its id

As for "should data be duplicated and updated when needed", this is very common with NoSQL so don't worry about it.